# Format disk with one Windows and one Mac partition

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, filesystem

Can I partition an internal hard disk (in a Mac Pro or Mac Mini) such that it contains one partition usable for Mac OS and one usable for Windows?

I know Boot Camp does that for the boot disk but I wonder if it will work for a second disk as well?

Basically I want the system to start either Windows or Mac and use the second disk for data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 hard drives you can do this way:
1) On 1st drive install osx. Then use bootcamp assistant to re-partition the disk 1 and install windows on second partition. At this point you can via disk utility format the second drive as you wish (e.g.: second drive 1Tb= 500gb fat/ntfs for win data and 500gb hfs+ for osx data);
2) On 1st drive install osx. Then use bootcamp assistant and select secondary hd (not the osx' one) and install windows. Now you have dual boot on 2 separate disk, 1 fully dedicated to osx and one to windows.

Comment: Method 1 is what I was looking for. Have you tried this out or do you just assume that it will work?

Comment: I've got this setup up and running atm onto my laptop (replaced optical drive with second hd).